# PostgreSQL SELECT attributes from a Custom type in a function

Tags: sql, function, postgresql-9.2

Here is my type:

```
CREATE TYPE occupant AS (name text, title title);
```

And here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE office (id INTEGER DEFAULT NEXTVAL('venue_id_seq'),occupant occupant) INHERITS(venue);
```

and then this is my function:

```
 CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION occupantName(id int) RETURNS text AS 
$$
  SELECT occupant.tile + occupant.name FROM office as v WHERE id = v.id;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

It is giving me this error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ocupant"
LINE 15:       SELECT ocupant.tile + ocupant.name FROM office as v WH...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use parenthesis around occupant to access composite type fields:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION occupantName(id int) RETURNS text AS 
$$
  SELECT (occupant).tile || (occupant).name FROM office as v WHERE id = v.id;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: Just to add to your answer I also had to use TEXTCAT(,) instead of the + sign

Comment: or || concatenation operator

Comment: @RomanPekar Thanks for your answer. This saved me countless hours of debugging.